# Bug en el generador de urls

Tags: bug, acentos

Revisando esta pregunta que en algún momento tuvo en su título una **Ó** (O con acento ortográfico mayúscula)

[Como puedo aplicar la programación orientada a objetos en c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91529/como-puedo-aplicar-la-programaci%C3%B3n-orientada-a-objetos-en-c)

Me dí con la sorpresa que al generar la url de la pregunta en el título de la Ó no fue convertida a minúsculas Ó --> ó

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un problema menor sobretodo porque los caracteres en el último segmento de la url después del id no contribuyen a que el link funcione o falle, pero de todos modos es algo que molesta.

Comment: Yo la veo en minúsculas. ¿Será cosa de la caché local?

Comment: me too.. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91529/como-puedo-aplicar-la-programaci%C3%B3n-orientada-a-objetos-en-c

Comment: Ya la edité porque estaba escrito innecesariamente en mayúsculas, pero el problema persiste.

Comment: Intenta en otro país XD

Comment: ¿O tal vez deberíamos dejarlo an mayúsculas hasta que se solucione el problema y poder verficarlo?

Comment: Se entiende sin necesidad de volver a modificar la pregunta. Vale aclarar que es puramente estético, ya que lo que aparece después del ID puede ser cualquier cosa, e incluso algo como https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91529/ÁÉÍÓÚ van a llevar a la misma publicación... El tema con las mayúsculas es sencillo en español, pero bastante más complicado si se consideran todos los lenguajes (turco por ejemplo)

Answer (score -1):

Como mencioné en mi [comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2601/bug-en-el-generador-de-urls#comment9089_2601), antes de que el OP revirtiera el cambio, yo lo veía bien siendo que [él comentaba](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2601/bug-en-el-generador-de-urls#comment9091_2601) que

> Ya la edité porque estaba escrito innecesariamente en mayúsculas, pero el problema persiste.

He aquí la prueba (captura de pantalla antes de que el OP revirtiera el cambio)

[image]

Cabe mencionar que no había accedido antes a esa pregunta, así que si el problema le persistía al OP en su equipo podría tratarse del autocompletado de URLs de su navegador.

En Chrome, para eliminar uno de los URL de la lista de autocompletado, cuando se muestra la lista, usar las flechas para resaltar la que corresponde y luego presiona <kbd>Mayúsculas</kbd> + <kbd>Suprimir</kbd>

En otros navegadores podría funcionar lo mismo.

Comment: Ya había editado el título para que se vea bien, pero ya lo revertí a mayúsculas para evitar confusiones

Comment: Me parece que has sobrereaccionado, pero siendo algo tan trivial, este  comentario también parece sobrereaccionado :)

Comment: A mi lo que me parece es que es incorrecto, por más pequeño que sea

Comment: Me refería a hacer el cambio al título de la pregunta y luego revertirlo en tan poco tiempo, menos de una hora en la que publicaste la pregunta en Meta. Lo de bug, debería ser investigado y priorizado apropiadamente. Tal vez el bug sea la inconsistencia en la generación del URL ya que si todas las demás letras se muestran en minúsculas, las mayúsculas con acentos también deberían mostrarse en minúsculas. Lo de que en el navegador no se actualice el URL es meramente circunstancial.